# How to select specific data from a while statement by comparing values?

Tags: php

The title is pretty much self-explanatory. I'm trying to select a specific plan from a while statement by comparing values together and returning the plan details in an array I can use with jQuery.

```
$compareme = some integer;

while($plan = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultplans)) {

$finalpricing = round($plan['price']);
$planname = $plan['name'];
$plandescription = $plan['description']'

if($compareme == $finalpricing){

//select the plan with the same pricing as $compareme
 //create json array that can be used with jQuery
  $planArray = array(
                      'planName' => $planname,
                      'planPrice' => $finalpricing,
                      'planDescription' => $plandescription
                    );
  //encode in json
  header('Content-Type: application/json');
  echo json_encode($planArray);  
}
} <-- end of while loop-->
```

Now let's pretend that two plans A and B return with same pricing. Is there a way of only selecting one plan? It does not matter which one gets selected. I just need to return one.

Comment: It will be better if you use your `$comparame` variable in the Where clause of your query

Answer (score 0):

Add a `break ;` after your `echo json_encode($planArray);` and it will exit your while loop.

```
echo json_encode($planArray); 
break ;
```